# Error al instanciar componente hijo en React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Siempre hice HTML y CSS. Estoy empezando a estudiar React y sinceramente no entiendo el porqué del error. Es algo muy básico y quería saber si alguien me lo puede explicar. Muchas Gracias !!

```
import React from 'react';
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

    class ItemLista extends React.Component {
        render () {
            return (
                <li>
                    <span>Nombre: {this.props.name}</span>
                    <span>Mail: {this.props.mail}</span>
                </li>
            );
        }
    }

    class CuerpoLista extends React.Component {
        render () {
            return (
                <ul>
                    {this.props.users.map(u => {
                        return (
                            <ItemLista 
                                key={u.id}
                                name={u.name}
                                mail={u.mail}
                            />
                        );
                    })}
                </ul>
            )
        }
    }

    class App extends React.Component {
        constructor() {
            super();
            this.state = {
                users: [
                    {id: 1, name: "Sebastián", mail: "hetsahk.il@gmail.com"},
                    {id: 2, name: "Noelia", mail: "juanascorda@gmail.com"}
                ]
            };
        }

        render () {
            return (
                <CuerpoLista users="this.state.users" />
            );
        }
    }

    ReactDOM.render(
        <App />,
        document.getElementById('root')
    )
```

Comment: ¿Cual es tu pregunta?

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio Sebastian!, te sugiero leer [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y realiza el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Había escrito un texto. Se ve que en el copy paste del código lo borré. Pido disculpas. Siempre hice HTML y Css. Estoy empezando a estudiar React y sinceramente no entiendo el porqué del error. Es algo muy básico y quería saber si alguien me lo puede explicar

Comment: Pon eso mismo en tu pregunta, cambia el título a algo como "Error al instanciar componente hijo en React.js" y escribe una breve introducción a la pregunta en vez de pegar el código tal cual. Y pon específicamente tu pregunta (en este caso es obvia a partir del título, pero se supone que no tenemos que deducir tu duda)

Comment: Ahí corregí la pregunta, muchas gracias por los tips y disculpen los errores!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En tu clase `App` renderizas la siguiente línea:

```
<CuerpoLista users="this.state.users" />
```

cuando deberías encerrar la propiedad entre llaves:

```
<CuerpoLista users={this.state.users} />
```

Luego, en el componente `CuerpoLista` no sé si te funcione así, pero con la estructura de `=>` no necesitas especificar el `return`, yo lo dejaría simplemente así:

```
render () {
    return (
        <ul>
            {this.props.users.map(u => <ItemLista 
                                          key={u.id}
                                          name={u.name}
                                          mail={u.mail} />)}
        </ul>
    )
}
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, el problema estaba en las comillas, puse this.state.users entre {} y funcionó perfecto.

Comment: @SebastianMolinari Me alegra que así haya sido. No olvides marcar la respuesta como "correcta" (con la palomita que está a la izquierda, debajo del número grande) para indicar que te sirvió! :D